# urlManager rules not working on modules Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

I am trying to make some url rules in Yii 2 so I can access an action from the controller like this:

```
controller/action/1 -> controller/action (with a parameter)
```

I tried some rules but they won't work in my modules (www.example.com/midend, www.example.com/backend).

So, if I want to access `www.example.com/controller/action/1` it's works just fine but if I want to access `www.example.com/midend/controller/action/1` it return 404.

These are the rules for modules:

```
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>',
```

These are the rules without modules:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>',
```

I already tried to replace `<module:\w+>` with `midend`.

Comment: Why `<id:\w+>` and not `<id:\d+>` ?

Comment: @soju well, I copied the on from the action and replaced with id. Guess `\d` has more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your ids are integers, you should simply replace your rules by this one :

```
'<controller>/<action>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

It will work for :

- www.example.com/controller
- www.example.com/controller/action
- www.example.com/controller/action/1
- www.example.com/module (assuming you have a default controller)
- www.example.com/module/controller
- www.example.com/module/controller/action
- www.example.com/module/controller/action/1

Comment: Thank you. I realised after that my ids are also chars so I replaced `\d` with `\w`. Worked perfect.